# Remove hook in wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, footer

There is a hook I want to remove, or stop from working from a template i am using -

```
     * FOOTER.PHP HOOKS
*/
// Footer hook
function copious_footer_hook() {
    do_action('copious_footer_hook');
}
```

How can I make this void or stop it?

Comment: you can also pass null function.

Comment: deleting it caused the entire site to go down, i had to go into my file manager and add it back

Answer (score 1):

```
remove_action( 'copious_footer_hook' );
```

For more information or options, check: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action